# Microsoft Access database adding multiple row in form

Tags: ms-access

I have created the database in access, to enter daily inspection data, some time for one item we have to add multiple type rework entry and for that every time we have to select product name every time, and its time consuming

what I am trying to find that add multi-row in my form which will store different types to data in separate rows in the main table and product name will take automatically for all rows data

[image]

Comment: You can put a sub-form in the center of your form, and use a  datasheet type form for it. Is it resolve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i am new in this, can you please elaborate more in details?